# What's the difference between additional CSS in the customizer and editing the style.css file?

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

I've got a local server set up and i've been editing the CSS of my child theme in Dreamweaver. I've now seen, through the WordPress dashboard, the additional CSS area and the Appearance > Editor.

What's the difference between them and do I need to choose one and stick to it? I was testing some code in the additional CSS box and then erased it but now the stuff i'm writing in Dreamweaver isn't updating when i view my site through the WordPress dashboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you add css to the customizer's *Additional CSS* setting, that text/code is stored in the database. This is a good way to quickly modify the look of a pre-existing theme without creating a child theme (or editing the theme files, which would get overwritten during an theme update).

The customizer "Additional CSS" is useful for minor css tweaks. If you are making major theme modifications, you will want to use a child theme or modify your own theme.

Answer (score -1):

Custom CSS allows you to add your own styles or override the default CSS of a plugin or theme.

And CSS, or Cascading Styles Sheets, is a way to style and present HTML. Whereas the HTML is the meaning or content, the style sheet is the presentation of that document.

Comment: Writing CSS in Additional CSS is better than writing it in Style.css, Because style.css having a number of codes written. Easy to access Additional CSS

Comment: Do i have to choose just one? I don't know why it's not updating with my style.css anymore so i'm worried they've interfered with each other.

Comment: add "!important" beside every css eg. .body{display:none!impotant;}

Comment: I've just added it to: footer { display: none!important; }
But it's not updated in WordPress view site still

Comment: can you share Screenshots?

Answer (score -2):

If your newly added style rules doesn't seem to work you need to need to perform some troubleshooting steps

1. Scan your style file for missing **";"** which can prevent following style
   rules from being recognised.
2. Use **inspect** feature of your browser check for conflicts , style rules that override the css that doesn't work.
3. Test from a **different browser** and make sure that the css file loaded in your browser is the correct version not a previously cached one.

Here is a useful reference https://codex.wordpress.org/CSS_Troubleshooting

Also read about css priority and specificity rules.

you can use "!important" as a quick fix but it is not considered as a good practice.

Customizer settings are stored in the database and loaded after the main styles, lastly loaded rules override same previous rules if it has higher spesifisity.

Comment: Hi, so is it good practice to only edit the CSS in one way? For example, if i am editing the style.css file in Dreamweaver, should i avoid using Additional CSS or Appearance > Editor? Thanks

Comment: If you are the theme developer , use style.css mainly don't add too many rules for the same thing or you will end up with a cluttered file that can affect your theme load time. If you are working on another developer's theme , create a child theme if you will do much editing for small changes use the customizer.